# Why am I not able to pickup items in my text based game?

Tags: python

I am working on my text based adventure game project for my intro to scripting class, written in Python.

I have everything done and everything works except when I try to use the move

`"Get 'item name'"` I'm getting my own error that says it's an invalid command.

I've tried different indentations and such, but nothing has worked for me. I'm able to move around, and the boss message prints, realizing there are no items in my inventory.
I'm not asking for anyone to critique/re-do my code, just help me understand why that specific thing isn't working.
Here is what I have

```
def main_menu():
    # Print instructions and intro
    print("Vampire Adventure Game")
    print("Collect 6 items to win the game, or be slain by the vampire.")
    print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")


def move_between_rooms(current_room, move, rooms):
    # move to corresponding room
    current_room = rooms[current_room][move]
    return current_room


def get_item(current_room, move, rooms, inventory):
    # add item to inventory and remove it from the room
    inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
    del rooms[current_room]['item']


def main():
    # dictionary of connecting rooms with items
    rooms = {
        'Main Cellar': {'South': 'Butlers Quarters', 'North': 'Old Armory', 'East': 'Chapel', 'West': 'Mess Hall'},
        'Butlers Quarters': {'North': 'Main Cellar', 'East': 'Tool Room', 'item': 'Wooden stake'},
        'Tool Room': {'West': 'Butlers Quarters', 'item': 'Hammer'},
        'Old Armory': {'South': 'Main Cellar', 'West': 'Vampires Lair', 'East': 'Blacksmith', 'item': 'Plate armor'},
        'Blacksmith': {'West': 'Old Armory', 'item': 'Silver Sickle'},
        'Mess Hall': {'East': 'Main Cellar', 'item': 'Garlic'},
        'Chapel': {'West': 'Main Cellar', 'item': 'Unholy symbol'},
        'Vampires Lair': ''
    }
    s = ' '
    # list for storing player inventory
    inventory = []
    # starting room
    current_room = "Main Cellar"
    # show the player the main menu
    main_menu()

    while True:
        # handle the case when player encounters the 'villain'
        if current_room == 'Vampires Lair':
            # winning case
            if len(inventory) == 6:
                print('Congratulations you have defeated Lord Drakan and saved the town!')
                print('Thank you for playing!')
                break
            # losing case
            else:
                print('\nOh dear! You did not collect all of the items!')
                print('You were vanquished by Lord Drakan and the town was destroyed!')
                print('Thank you for playing!')
                break
        # Tell the user their current room, inventory and prompt for a move, ignores case
        print('You are in the ' + current_room)
        print(inventory)
        # tell the user if there is an item in the room
        if current_room != 'Vampires Lair' and 'item' in rooms[current_room].keys():
            print('You see the {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
        print('------------------------------')
        move = input('Enter your move: ').title().split()

        # handle if the user enters a command to move to a new room
        if len(move) >= 2 and move[1] in rooms[current_room].keys():
            current_room = move_between_rooms(current_room, move[1], rooms)
            continue
        # handle if the user enter a command to get an item
        elif len(move) == 4 and move[0] == 'Get' and s.join(move[1:3]) in rooms[current_room]['item']:
            print('You pick up the {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
            print('------------------------------')
            get_item(current_room, move, rooms, inventory)
            continue
        # handle if the user enters an invalid command
        else:
            print('Invalid move, please try again')
            continue


main()
```

Comment: If you type `Get 'item name'` then `len(move)` will be 3, not 4.

Comment: And if you type `get Hammer` it will be 2.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood that correctly, but I made it into len(move) >= 1 and now my silver sickle is working, but others aren't. I fear I'm more lost than I thought.

Comment: `get Unholy symbol` won't work because `.title()` changes the input to `Get Unholy Symbol`. The uppercase `S` doesn't match `Unholy symbol`.

Comment: Ahh okay, zybooks is an okay teaching tool but in situations like this it doesn't help very much. Thank you so much Barmar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with indexing. The problem is that the length of `move` differs if your item has a single word or two. Change this line:

```
elif len(move) == 4 and move[0] == 'Get' and s.join(move[1:3]) in rooms[current_room]['item']:
```

to this:

```
elif len(move[0]) == 3 and move[0] == 'Get' and ' '.join(move[1:]) in rooms[current_room]['item']:
```

Also, make the first letter for the second word of each item capital. E.g `Wooden stake` -> `Wooden Stake`.
Now you can put all items in your inventory.

Full working code:

```
def main_menu():
    # Print instructions and intro
    print("Vampire Adventure Game")
    print("Collect 6 items to win the game, or be slain by the vampire.")
    print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")


def move_between_rooms(current_room, move, rooms):
    # move to corresponding room
    current_room = rooms[current_room][move]
    return current_room


def get_item(current_room, move, rooms, inventory):
    # add item to inventory and remove it from the room
    inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
    del rooms[current_room]['item']


def main():
    # dictionary of connecting rooms with items
    rooms = {
        'Main Cellar': {'South': 'Butlers Quarters', 'North': 'Old Armory', 'East': 'Chapel', 'West': 'Mess Hall'},
        'Butlers Quarters': {'North': 'Main Cellar', 'East': 'Tool Room', 'item': 'Wooden Stake'},
        'Tool Room': {'West': 'Butlers Quarters', 'item': 'Hammer'},
        'Old Armory': {'South': 'Main Cellar', 'West': 'Vampires Lair', 'East': 'Blacksmith', 'item': 'Plate Armor'},
        'Blacksmith': {'West': 'Old Armory', 'item': 'Silver Sickle'},
        'Mess Hall': {'East': 'Main Cellar', 'item': 'Garlic'},
        'Chapel': {'West': 'Main Cellar', 'item': 'Unholy Symbol'},
        'Vampires Lair': ''
    }
    s = ' '
    # list for storing player inventory
    inventory = []
    # starting room
    current_room = "Main Cellar"
    # show the player the main menu
    main_menu()

    while True:
        # handle the case when player encounters the 'villain'
        if current_room == 'Vampires Lair':
            # winning case
            if len(inventory) == 6:
                print('Congratulations you have defeated Lord Drakan and saved the town!')
                print('Thank you for playing!')
                break
            # losing case
            else:
                print('\nOh dear! You did not collect all of the items!')
                print('You were vanquished by Lord Drakan and the town was destroyed!')
                print('Thank you for playing!')
                break
        # Tell the user their current room, inventory and prompt for a move, ignores case
        print('You are in the ' + current_room)
        print(inventory)
        # tell the user if there is an item in the room
        if current_room != 'Vampires Lair' and 'item' in rooms[current_room].keys():
            print('You see the {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
        print('------------------------------')
        move = input('Enter your move: ').title().split()

        # handle if the user enters a command to move to a new room
        if len(move) >= 2 and move[1] in rooms[current_room].keys():
            current_room = move_between_rooms(current_room, move[1], rooms)
            continue
        # handle if the user enter a command to get an item
        elif len(move[0]) == 3 and move[0] == 'Get' and ' '.join(move[1:]) in rooms[current_room]['item']:
            print('You pick up the {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
            print('------------------------------')
            get_item(current_room, move, rooms, inventory)
            continue
        # handle if the user enters an invalid command
        else:
            print('Invalid move, please try again')
            continue


main()
```

Comment: Why `move[4:]`? Shouldn't it be `move[1:]`?

Comment: Thank you so much, would you mind just telling me why it being 4: rather than 1:3? Is it because when its 4: its reading everything after the space after Get? The comment above helped me with the first part of this line, wondering why the change to the second one.

Comment: @ Both, E.g. from the string 'Get Hammer' we want to skip the "Get ", which is of length 4. move[4:] skips these first 4 characters, and takes the rest of the string.

Comment: After trying this, every single room works and the item is pickup-able except for the Hammer.. any ideas? :/

Comment: Yes, trying to see why it doesn't work for hammer.

Comment: I changed it to "Rusty hammer" and it worked..guess I could just have it be a rusty hammer! Garlic also doesn't work by itself.

Comment: It obviously has some issue with one-word items, still trying to see what's the matter.

Comment: I changed it into Old garlic! Haha, it isn't a huge deal I do appreciate you dedicating some time to looking into it though. I'm just glad I was able to produce this, especially with you guys help.

Comment: You 're welcome. If your question is answered, please mark the answer as accepted. In the meantime i'll try to see what's wrong with one-word items. Thanks for the game! ^^

Comment: If you mean by checking the green mark next to your answer, done! First time posting a question here sorry! and thank you guys a million times again!